# No need for the operator () in std::generate?

Tags: c++, operators

Why we don't add the operator () in `std::generate (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), RandomNumber)`? Being something like this: `std::generate (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), RandomNumber())`.

Code taken from cplusplus:

```
int RandomNumber () { return (std::rand()%100); }

int main () {
  std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );

  std::vector<int> myvector (8);

  std::generate (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), RandomNumber);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
```

Comment: The expression `RandomNumber()` evaluates to a function call, which returns an integer number. That's what happens when `foo` is a name of a function that returns an `int`, and you write `foo()`. That's what happens in C++, that's how it works. So, for example, the returned integer number might be 4. Does `std::generate(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 4);` make sense to you?

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116060/understanding-the-use-of-operator-function-object

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i understand the std::generate(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 4) but i didnt understand really well the no need for () operator in RandomNumber

Comment: Because `()` means a function call in C++ (at least in this context). When you write `function_name()`, your're calling the function. Hard rule, no exceptions. `function_name`, by itself, evaluates to a pointer to the function. A pointer to a function is a callable object. The third parameter to `generate()` can be any callable object, not just a class that implements an `operator()` overload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Function pointers and functors are not the same thing**

`RandomNumber` is the name of a function. It'll decay to a function pointer here. That's one way to pass a callable to algorithms like `std::generate`.

Another way is to create a *type*, a *class*, a *functor*, which has a call operator (`operator()`). We can also pass an instance of this type to algorithms like `std::generate`, and the algorithm will "call the object like a function" instead of using a function pointer.

When we do that, we sometimes instantiate it as a temporary, for brevity. So, for example, this:

```
Type obj;
f(obj);
```

is much like this:

```
f(Type());
```

*(except that would be suspectible to the most vexing parse in this simple example; just ignore that :P)*

So, the `()` you're looking for is a class instantiation, which just isn't relevant when you pass a function pointer instead of a functor.

If you wrote `RandomNumber()`, you'd simply be calling the function `RandomNumber` and passing its result to `std::generate`, which is not what you want.